# SQL Server 2012 JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

The company’s vice-president for project management needs a listing of all employees and the number of hours they have worked on various projects. The result table should list the employee’s last and first names (emp_last_name and emp_first_name), project number (work_pro_number), and hours worked (work_hours).

The result table should list all employees, whether they are assigned to work on a project. Use alias names for the table names. Give each column an appropriate column name. Use CAST and CONVERT commands to product a listing that fits easily on one page. Sort the output by emp_last_name and emp_first_name. Which employees or employees are assigned to a project, but have not worked any hours on a project?

Using `JOIN`, `ORDER BY` and combine the First and Last Name into one column

okay. Yes now I have :

```
SELECT  
   emp_last_name "Last Name", 
   emp_first_name "Employee First Name", 
   work_pro_number "Project Number", 
   work_hours "Hours Worked" 
FROM 
   employee e 
JOIN 
   assignment a ON (e.emp_superssn = a.work_emp_ssn) 
ORDER BY 
   emp_last_name`
```

but I'm still having a problem with people who work in different project numbers. i.e. Hyder Amin works in project numbers 20 and 30 how do i combine so it will have Hyer amin and the both projects listed 20, 30 (or something)

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: im not exactly sure what you mean. I just need to know how to have the Project Number Column to display multiple project numbers. Because employees belong to multiple projects.

Comment: how will this project number column displays multiple project no? what i mean is to give sample records in tabular format and show us what is your desired result.

Comment: [\[click\] see this question, it has sample records and a desired result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please tried with below query..

```
select e.emp_last_name, 
    e.emp_first_name,
    (SELECT stuff(( SELECT ', ' + convert(varchar(10),work_pro_number) FROM assignment WHERE e.emp_superssn = assignment.work_emp_ssn FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'')) AS work_pro_number,
    sum(work_hours) AS work_hours 
FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN assignment a ON e.emp_superssn = a.work_emp_ssn
GROUP BY e.emp_last_name, e.emp_first_name, e.emp_superssn
ORDER BY emp_last_name, emp_first_name
```