# How to get "LAST RECORD WITH COUNT (MySql)"?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named "articles".
article(id,article,category,title).
My table structure is as follows :

TABLE :

```
+----+-------------------------+---------------+
| id | article| category       | title         |
+----+-------------------------+---------------+
| 1  | a1     | a              | ta1           |
| 2  | a2     | a              | ta2           |
| 3  | b1     | b              | tb1           |
| 4  | b2     | b              | tb2           |
| 5  | b3     | b              | tb3           |
| 6  | c1     | c              | tc1           |
| 7  | c2     | c              | tc2           |
| 8  | c3     | c              | tc3           |
+----+-------------------------+---------------+
```

One "category" can have mutiple "article" related to it, that is number of article can belong to same category. I have to find COMPLETE record of the last entered article in each category.

```
SELECT id,article,category,title FROM articles
WHERE article IN(SELECT MAX(article) FROM articles GROUP BY category)
```

This query gives :

```
+----+-------------------------+-------+
| id | article| category       | title |
+----+-------------------------+-------+
| 2  | a2     | a              | ta2   |
| 5  | b3     | b              | tb3   |
| 8  | c3     | c              | tc3   |
+----+-------------------------+--------
```

NOW along with this OUTPUT, i have to find COUNT of articles in each category.
My required OUtput is:

```
+----+-------------------------+-------+-------+
| id | article| category       | title | Count |
+----+-------------------------+-------+-------+
| 2  | a2     | a              | ta2   | 2     |
| 5  | b3     | b              | tb3   | 3     |
| 8  | c3     | c              | tc3   | 3     |
+----+-------------------------+----------------+
```

Help me with the query ????????/

Comment: how do you know if it;s the last inputted article? what is the structure of your table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate subquery which calculates the latest article and count the total article for each category, the result of the subquery is then joined back on the original table to get the other columns,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.total_article
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  category, 
                    MAX(Article) last_article, 
                    COUNT(*) total_article
            FROM    articles
            GROUP   BY category
        ) b ON  a.category = b.category AND
                a.Article = b.last_article
```

Comment: what is your desired output based on the example given? can you make it in tabular format? [*sample records with desired result in tabular format*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows/15656384)

Comment: +----+-------------------------+--------------+
| id | article| category       | title         |
+----+-------------------------+--------------+
| 1  | a1     | a              | ta1            |
| 2  | a2     | a              | ta2            |
| 3  | b1     | b              | tb1            |
| 4  | b2     | b              | tb2           |
| 5  | b3     | b              | tb3          |
+----+-------------------------+--------------+

Comment: how do you know that certain record is the latest among the group? that's what i'm confused of.

Comment: and lastly, please post the records along with your question to make it readable.

Comment: i am new user of this site: I used same format to PRINT table,it reflect sytematically while ediiting. but unable to print same  fomatized table after SAVING it

Comment: first, thank you for adding sample record. [Here is the demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/621f8/1)

Comment: Thanks , but i already got my answer using RIGHT JOIN posted above. Can u suggest me which is better to use and why?

Comment: @user2227393 I guessing that you will soon get back here and tell us that the value on some columns do not really match on the each row. Read this: [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 0):

I GOT My OUTPUT using :

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.title,
       a.article,
       a.category,
       b.LastArticle,
       b.TotalArticles
FROM article a
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT id,
          title,
          article,
          category,
          max(article) LastArticle,
          count(article) TotalArticles
   FROM article
   GROUP BY category) b ON b.LastArticle = a.article
```

Thanks to those, who tried to help

Answer (score -1):

Try using MySQL [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Try this:

```
SELECT id, article, category, title, COUNT(1) count
FROM articles
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This will return the result with the highest `id` value for every `category` as well as the number of articles for each category.

Comment: @user2227393 - See my edit for the addition of the `COUNT()` aggregate function. Misread your initial question.