# MySQL : merging records from two similar tables while avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

Is there a simple way in MySQL to merge the content of two similar tables (same fields) while avoiding duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that they are similar tables, you can use `UNION`, without specifying `ALL`, it will just return unique rows.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
```

Comment: Thanks J W. But this won't achieve merging, it will only display something isn't it?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by merging? it maybe combining or joining? can you give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: Sorry I'll clarify: table A contains say 200 posts, table B contains these same posts plus 100 different posts. I want A to contains these 100 posts on top of the 200 posts they both have in common.

Comment: [See this question to understand what I mean by *sample records with desired result*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows/15656384). What are these post? how do they look like?

Comment: They are WordPress posts. I want to merge the wp_posts table of one WP install with the wp_posts table of another.

Comment: So you just want to add records form B to A. Do the tables have usable primary keys? (or even better: *natural* keys)

Comment: Well I want to add B's records to A only if A doesn't have them already. Each post does have an ID yes.

Comment: can you give even just a screenshot? so you will not give any typing..

Comment: The Id is likely to be a surrogate key or serial. For duplicate-detection you will need some kind of natural key (such as date+content).

Comment: Screenshot : http://alturl.com/omjmu