# MySQL Query left join repeated records

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

With a Left Join i have this result.

Here the screen
http://f.cl.ly/items/373Y141r1K131d0n3f1q/Schermata%202013-04-01%20alle%2016.51.18.png

i want to show only record once time, without repeat it, but with a left join all my records are different.
what i have to do for show once all my records?

the query.

```
 SELECT * FROM login_users
 LEFT JOIN login_users_seguaci
 ON login_users.user_id = login_users_seguaci.following
 WHERE name LIKE ""
 AND user_id != '1'
 ORDER BY data DESC
```

Comment: Give us some data from the tables...it seems you have duplicates in the table:login_users_seguaci or login_users, is it normal?( if not there you have it:) )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  x.*, y.*
FROM    login_users x
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.*
            FROM    login_users_seguaci a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  following, MAX(DATA) max_data
                        FROM    login_users_seguaci
                        GROUP   BY following
                    ) b ON  a.following = b.following AND
                            a.DATA = b.max_date
        ) y ON x.user_id = y.following
//  WHERE   ... your condition here ...
ORDER   BY t.data DESC
```

Comment: @KA_lin when i done left join i found these results.
i don't want to found records with the same "user_id".
so I have to find a solution for this problem.

@J W unknow "b.max_date".

Comment: what is exactly your desired resut? can you give sample data with desired result like [this question (click)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows/15656384)