# how to join 3 tables, topic, comment and user

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables, tbl_topic, tbl_comment, tbl_user.
I want to select all the topics created by the user and also the topics that he commented on even if he is not the creator. Here is my database:

```
tbl_topic
----------
topic_id
topic_title
user_id

tbl_comment
----------
comment_id
comment_message
user_id
topic_id

tbl_user
----------
user_id
user_name
```

Need it so badly. Thanks!

So far i got this

```
select * from tbl_topic T inner join tbl_comment C on T.topic_id = C.topic_id inner join tbl_user U on T.user_id = U.user_id GROUP BY T.topic_id
```

My problem is it only returns the topics that has comments on it. I want to include the topics created by the user even if it has 0 comments.

I want the result to be like this:

```
  +-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------
    | topic_id | topic_title | user_id | comment_id | comment_message | user_id | topic_id | 
    +-----------+-----------+----------+-------------+----------------+----------+--------
    | 1         | my topic  |   1      | 1          | comment me      | 1       |  1
    | 2         | others    |   2      | 2          | comment me      | 1       |  2
    | 3         | my nocoment|  1      | NULL       | NULL            | NULL    | NULL
    +-----------+---------+--------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+--------

     ----------+-----------+
         user_id | user_name |
        -----------+-----------
         1         | me       |
         2         | someone  |
         1         | me
        -----------+---------+--
```

I messed up with my fields in my tables, the user_id beside comment_message should be comment_user_id but i already created my database that way. Can you help make this possible?

Comment: Better paste what you have tried already..!

Comment: You are referring to the activities done by the user am I right?

Comment: if that's the case you have to use left outer join for comments, then UNION for the activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below uses `UNION` in the subquery. The *first* `SELECT` gets all topics created by user. The *second* `SELECT` statement gets all comments of the user and joins it to table `tbl_topic` so we can get the `topic_title`.

```
SELECT  topic_ID, topic_title
FROM
        (
            SELECT  a.user_ID, b.topic_ID, b.topic_title
            FROM    tbl_user a
                    INNER JOIN tbl_topic b
                        ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
            UNION
            SELECT  a.user_ID, c.topic_ID, c.topic_title
            FROM    tbl_user a
                    INNER JOIN tbl_comment b
                        ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID
                    INNER JOIN tbl_topic c
                        ON b.topic_ID = c.topic_ID
        ) x
WHERE   x.user_ID = ?
```

Comment: Sir, see the update? What if the user has a post and with no comment? I think you have to use outer join for that.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow that's the reason why i'm using `UNION`. This can also be done using outer join but still need a subquery.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow as i've read the question `select all the topics created by the user and also the topics that he commented on even if he is not the creator` -- didn't say post that needs comment.

Comment: I got it, so the 1st subquery will determine the post and the 2nd subquery will determine the comments done by the user.

Comment: Thank you @J W! This works just fine. I forgot the union thing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @J W, one problem, i need to display the creator of the topic and also its comments. The problem with your script is that it only reads 1 user_id, so when I echo the username, only 1 user is appearing.

Comment: can you give sample record with your desired result in tablular format just like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows/15656384)?

Comment: I mean all the topics echoes the same creator, my problem is even if the user is not the creator, it should appear when he commented on it.  In my query above, this is not a problem and my only problem to that is it doesn't echo topics that has zero comments. please update. Thanks

Comment: there is a little misunderstanding here. Do you want to get the topics created and commented on a specific user? As you can see there are two queries being unioned above. the first select statement gets all topics created by the user (*whether it has comments or not*). On the second query, table `tbl_user` is linked to `tbl_comment` to get all the topics commented and joined it with `tbl_topic` to get the title of the topic. So what is the problem here?

Comment: i just want to echo the topic along with its creator. When I use your script, It only echoes 1 user, which is the value of x.user_id. Try it.

Comment: can you give sample records?  how can I try if i have no records available?

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below. This will show all the fields.

```
SELECT tt.*, tc.*, tbl_user.*
FROM tbl_topic AS tt INNER JOIN tbl_comment AS tc ON tt.topic_id = tc.topic_id INNER JOIN tbl_user as tc ON tc.user_id = tu.user_id;
WHERE tu.user_id = x
```

If you have to filter add to the `WHERE` clause to the query.

Comment: don't forget to add a WHERE user_id = x :)

Answer (score 0):

Go with a left join. But there is still a Problem left, you will only get ONE table-comment and ONE user. To get more, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT function, like here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
select * from tbl_topic T 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_comment C on T.topic_id = C.topic_id 
    LEFT join tbl_user U on T.user_id = U.user_id 
WHERE T.user_id = x
GROUP BY T.topic_id
```

EDIT: the where clause was missing

Comment: how will this satisfy the problem? this will return all topics available whether the user has created or not.