# Modifying column value according to status, and adding extra rows. (sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my table I have a "name" column and a "status" column.
the status is either true or false.
And another table contains a number which is a total amount.

The result that I want to get is a table with two columns: 
name | status
and and example of a data:

a | available
a | available
a | not available
a | not available
a | available

when "a" is in the name column and the availability is the status column.

The total amount from the second table indicates the total number of "a" rows that i need to have, and the status depends on the true/false from the status column in the original table.

If the status is "true" I need to write "available" and when "false" then "not available".

If the total amount value is bigger than the data I have in the first table, I need to add rows according to the total amount with the status "available".

For example, If I have 3 records of "a", when one has the status "true" and the other two have the status "false", and the total amount is 4, In the result I need to get 4 rows with the name "a", 2 of them "available" and 2 "not available" (the given 3 rows, plus one row to make it 4).

My question is, how can I change the value according to the data in the table? (Write available/ not available)
And how can I add a certain amount of rows with preset values (same name as before, and "available" status)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"...how can I change the value according to the data in the table?"*

You can use `CASE()` to test for the value of the column.

```
SELECT  name,
        CASE WHEN status = 'true' 
            THEN 'available' 
            ELSE 'not available' 
        END status
FROM    tableName
```

Comment: can you clarify more on your second second?

Comment: Sure. tnx for the first part :) I have two tables. one has a number that is the total amount of copies I have of the same item, and the second says if some copies are available or not. The ones that are not in the second table are available by default. In my result table I need to show the status of each one of these copies. The ones that are in the second table are either available or not according to the data, and the remaining ones, if any, should be added as "available"

Comment: If you think it is impossible, it will help me too, then I will just try to find another solution, maybe change something in the tables or whatever...

Comment: [Can you give *sample records with desired result for the second question* just like this question (click) so I can visualize more and so we can play with the values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows/15656384)

Comment: Actually I thought about anther way to do it, adding a table with more detailed stuff, and then I don't need to add fake rows cos I will have all the data... so thanks for the first part! I still need it :) so I will choose your answer, and thanks a lot again :))

Comment: gee thanks. If you have any questions, just drop me a comment `:D`

Answer (score 0):

For future answer-seekers:

To get the 'fake' rows, one way is to use are recursive CTE:

```
WITH Expanded_Data as (SELECT Counted_Data.name, 
                              CAST('true' as VARCHAR(5)) as status, 
                              Counted_Data.count + 1 as count, 
                              Total.count as limit
                       FROM (SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count
                             FROM Data 
                             GROUP BY name) Counted_Data
                       JOIN Total 
                         ON Counted_Data.name = Total.name
                            AND Counted_Data.count < Total.count
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT name, status, count + 1, limit
                       FROM Expanded_Data 
                       WHERE count < limit)

SELECT name, CASE WHEN status = 'true' 
                  THEN 'available'
                  ELSE 'not available' END
FROM (SELECT name, status
      FROM Data
      UNION ALL
      SELECT name, status
      FROM Expanded_Data) d;
```

(have a working [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/082ab/22).)

I'm a little worried about the initial duplication in the source data though; I can only hope there is more 'unique' information as well.