# MySQL Relational Division with multiple IDs

Tags: mysql, relational-division

Please take a look at the question described here: [MySQL ONLY IN() equivalent clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461707/mysql-only-in-equivalent-clause) , regarding Relational Division in MySQL.

My database structure is very similar to the one described, but in the "Chocolate Boys Table", I have an additional ID field - let's call it milk ID.

Chocolates Boys Table

```
+----+---------+-----------------------+
| id | chocolate_id | milk id | boy_id |
+----+--------------+---------+--------+
| 1  | 1000         | 2000    | 10007  |
| 2  | 1003         | 2001    | 10007  |
| 3  | 1006         | 2005    | 10007  |
| 4  | 1000         | 2001    | 10009  |
| 5  | 1001         | 2000    | 10009  |
| 6  | 1005         | 2008    | 10009  |
+----+--------------+---------+--------|
```

The objective is to run a query that retrieves the boy ID that contains the exact chocolate and milk IDs that I pass in.  Here are some examples of my expected results:

Example #1:

```
Chocolate IDs Passed In (in order) - 1000,1003,1006.
Milk IDs Passed In (in order) - 2000,2001,2005.
Expected Result: Query returns boy ID of 10007.
```

Example #2:

```
Chocolate IDs Passed In (in order) - 1000,1003.
Milk IDs Passed In (in order) - 2000,2001.
Expected Result: Empty result set.
```

Example #3:

```
Chocolate IDs Passed In (in order) - 1003,1000,1006.
Milk IDs Passed In (in order) - 2000,2001,2005.
```

Expected Result: Empty result set - The passed in IDs are included in boy ID 10007, but the order is wrong.  The values of Chocolate ID and Milk ID don't match up if examined on a row by row basis.

I am attempting to use a slightly modified version of John Woo's solution in order to incorporate the added ID field:

```
SELECT boy_id 
FROM   boys_chocolates a
WHERE  chocolate_id IN (1003,1000,1006) AND milk_id IN (2000,2001,2005) AND
    EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    boys_chocolates b
        WHERE   a.boy_ID = b.boy_ID
        GROUP   BY boy_id
        HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT chocolate_id) = 3
    )
GROUP  BY boy_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

The problem that I'm having is that the IN function does not enforce order, as seen in example #3.  I would like the above query to return an empty result set.  What needs to be changed in order to address this problem?  Thank you!

Comment: if it was me, I'd forget about the milk and focus on the chocolate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
SELECT a.boy_id
FROM
  (SELECT id, boy_id FROM boys_chocolates WHERE chocolate_id = 1000) a
JOIN
(
  (SELECT id, boy_id FROM boys_chocolates WHERE chocolate_id = 1003) b,
  (SELECT id, boy_id FROM boys_chocolates WHERE chocolate_id = 1006) c,
  (SELECT id, boy_id FROM boys_chocolates WHERE milk_id = 2000) d,
  (SELECT id, boy_id FROM boys_chocolates WHERE milk_id = 2001) e,
  (SELECT id, boy_id FROM boys_chocolates WHERE milk_id = 2005) f
)
ON a.boy_id = b.boy_id AND a.boy_id = c.boy_id AND a.boy_id = d.boy_id 
  AND a.boy_id = e.boy_id AND a.boy_id = f.boy_id AND b.id > a.id 
  AND c.id > b.id AND e.id > d.id AND f.id > e.id;
```

Replace `1000` `1003` `1006` with your first chocolate_id, second chocolate_id, third chocolate_id respectively. Also replace `2000` `2001` `2005` with your first milk_id, second milk_id, third milk_id.