# Getting data from buddys, friends, and users table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to get friends feeds for the session user. But I end up with either nothing, or still everyone can see it.

Table format
http://pastebin.com/XGYmpi5u

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `protected` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feeds` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buddys` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_one` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `user_two` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

So my question is, how can I get the users data, and feeds that they've posted and the buddys feeds. Where only the users who are friends with the buddy can only see the posts they've made not anyone else.

I've tried the code:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    if ($getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feeds f
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.user_id 
    WHERE u.user_id = '$user_id' OR u.user_id IN 
    (SELECT b.user_one OR b.user_two FROM buddys b 
    WHERE b.user_one OR b.user_two = '$user_id')")){
```

But that shows the correct users feeds but also the user who is friends with either of the friends can still see the posts.

The users and feeds table have similar columns like.

```
+---+----------+
| ID | user_id |
+---+----------+
```

While buddys has

```
+----+----------+----------+
| ID | user_one | user_two |
+----+----------+----------+
```

If the tables have fields set as

```
+----+----------+---------+
| ID | user_one | user_two| 
+----+----------+---------+
| 1  |    3     |   5     |
+----+----------+---------+
```

I'd like to grab it by my ID if it's 3 and get the feeds from user ID 5.

Btw, I'm looking to have it like what Facebook/Twitter have it as.

Comment: can you also post some sample records and your desired result in tabular format?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "result"

Comment: [See this question to understand what I mean by *sample records with desired result*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656273/mysql-pivot-table-column-data-as-rows/15656384)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I haven't read all of your question, but...

your subquery here:

```
... OR u.user_id IN 
    (SELECT b.user_one OR b.user_two FROM buddys b 
    WHERE b.user_one OR b.user_two = '$user_id')
```

You can't write it like this. `b.user_one OR b.user_two` actually becomes a boolean expression, where `0` is false and everything else is true. So your query is basically

```
... OR u.user_id IN 
    (0, 1)
```

You have to use `UNION` to get both columns into one.

```
... OR u.user_id IN 
    (SELECT b.user_one FROM buddys b 
     WHERE b.user_one = '$user_id'
     UNION
     SELECT b.user_two FROM buddys b 
     WHERE b.user_two = '$user_id'
    )
```

Hope this solves your problem already. If not, give me a quick feedback and I'll read the whole question :)

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now I'm using$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   if ($getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feeds f
   LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = f.user_id 
   WHERE u.user_id = '$my_id' OR u.user_id IN 
    (SELECT b.user_one FROM buddys b 
    WHERE b.user_one = '$my_id' 
    UNION
    SELECT b.user_two FROM buddys b 
    WHERE b.user_two = '$my_id'
    )")){

Comment: Like others already commented, it's really hard to understand what you're after. So I'm joining them in asking for sample data and desired result based on that sample data.

Comment: Simplified it in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888692/friends-system-connected-to-news-feeds